# Symfony - Twig - Ovverride error page template

Tags: symfony, twig, custom-error-pages

Following the lead of the cookbook: 
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

The custom error pages are never rendered in production. If I understand correctly the problem is shared by many on the web. Does anyone know of a method that really works?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom exception listener which will for example render some template.

See the similiar post: [Symfony2 Custom Error Exception Listener - Rendering templates or passing to a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256252/symfony2-custom-error-exception-listener-rendering-templates-or-passing-to-a-c)