# handle and personalize symfony no route found exception response

Tags: symfony, exception, response

I have a controller that response a json data to another application , this is the controller code :

```
/**
     *
     * @Get("/getXXX/{id}")
     */
    public function getDataAction($id,Request $request){

        $ceService = $this->container->get('comptexpertcews.service');
        $employeNumber= $request->get('employeNumber') ;

         $url = $this->container->getParameter('serverUri') . $id;

        $res = new Response();
        $res->setContent($ceService->getCews($url, wsUrl::ws_Headers));
        $res->headers->set('Content-TYpe','application/json; charset=UTF-8');

        return $res;
    }
```

The problem is by default , if you don't give id in the url , symfony rise exception : not route foundexception , what i want is to handle the exception and personalize with my owner response like sending 
`{"error" :" id undefined "}`
instead of the long message expcetion of symfony

Comment: try google http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: i want to personalise the reponse in the controller not error in twig page , i 'm not using twig at all

Comment: set the default for the $id parameter in the route config (so that symfony does not throw an error), and then just handle it yourself inside you action (or abstracted somewhere else)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Custom Error Exception Listener - Rendering templates or passing to a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256252/symfony2-custom-error-exception-listener-rendering-templates-or-passing-to-a-c)

Comment: ok :) 
can you take a look in the link above and tell me what priority means here :
 - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException, priority: 200 }

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli They write about it [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two simple options:

1. Don't use param converter, get you data from a repository and then you can wrap it in `try catch` and create your own exception/message
2. If this is something you want to do globally, you can implement an event listener that catches `onKernelException` event and work with it from there, e.g.:

   ```
   public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event): void
   {
       $exception = $event->getException();

       if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
           $response = $this->resourceNotFoundResponse(json_encode($exception->getMessage()));
       }

       if (isset($response)) {
           $event->setResponse($response);
       }
   }
   ```

You also need to register you listener as a service, see the documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

Comment: excatly , i already found it here  :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256252/symfony2-custom-error-exception-listener-rendering-templates-or-passing-to-a-c